# PowerPoint random name picker with imported list of names

Tags: list, random, powerpoint, generator

I have made a random name picker which I have currently just added a text box in each of 20 slides and put the macros code to randomize once cursor is hovered over a box which works fine however I'd like to have a list of names that I can just type into and edit and have each text box in each slide read from that list rather than manually editing each text box each time its used.
I would also like to have code in the randomizer macros so that a player that gets picked cannot be picked again.
Is this possible?
Thanks.

[image of powerpoint file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0VDs.jpg)

The code so far:

```
Sub Randomiser() 
FirstSlide = 2 
LastSlide = 22 
Randomize 'generate a random no between first slide and last slide
GRN: 
RSN = Int((LastSlide - FirstSlide + 1) * Rnd + FirstSlide) 
If RSN = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex Then 
GoTo GRN 
End If 
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (RSN) 
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.State = ppSlideShowPaused 
End Sub
```

I have tried searching online for this but found things different to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you want this list to be in a text file or something else?  And post the code you have already; otherwise it's hard/impossible to explain how to accomplish what you're after.

Comment: Sub Randomiser()
FirstSlide = 2
LastSlide = 22

Randomize
'generate a random no between first slide and last slide'

GRN:
RSN = Int((LastSlide - FirstSlide + 1) * Rnd + FirstSlide)

If RSN = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex Then GoTo GRN
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (RSN)
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.State = ppSlideShowPaused
End Sub

Comment: Hi there, here is the randomizer code and what it looks like. each slide is just a master background and a text box that transitions over each slide. I would like it to be a list of names that either I can enter into a hidden slide and read from that or an excel file that can be linked and automatically read from that when its amended and auto change each tect box in the slides as to the names list.

Comment: As you can see, including code in a comment is a direct route to Illegibility City.  I've edited your original post, added the code there and reformatted. Please verify that I haven't introduced any errors.

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: Have a look here for some sample code from a PPTFAQ site I maintain. It should help you move ahead with this.  You'd still need to work out how to "flag" already used words/phrases. You might, for example, change each chosen array entry to "" after it's been chosen, and change the routine that makes the choices to one that loops until it finds a non-blank entry in the array of words. https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00570_Add_a_random_phrase_from_a_text_file_to_a_text_box_on_each_slide.htm